# Flutter: Errors when wrapping Layoutbuilder and Text in Column

Tags: flutter, listview, layout

I currently have a listview with an alphabet scroller on the side. I'm trying to add a searchbox to the top, but whenever I wrap something in a column, I get errors.
Using the current code, ListView inside Stack is throwing `Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.`

When I remove the column and Text('TestString'), my code works fine. I have tried adding an Expandable around the ListView.Builder but this also doesn't seem to solve it.

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text('TestString'),
          new LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (context, constraints) {
              return new Stack(children: [
                //Causes the current issue
                ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: exampleList.length,
                  controller: _controller,
                  itemExtent: _itemsizeheight,
                  itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                    return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 32.0),
                        child: Card(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                            child: Text(
                              exampleList[position],
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ));
                  },
                ),
                Positioned(
                    right: _marginRight,
                    top: _offsetContainer,
                    child: _getSpeechBubble()),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTapDown: (details) {
                      _onTapDown(details);
                    },
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onVerticalDragUpdate: _onVerticalDragUpdate,
                      onVerticalDragStart: _onVerticalDragStart,
                      onVerticalDragEnd: (details) {
                        setState(() {
                          isPressed = false;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        //height: 20.0 * 26,
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: new Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: []..addAll(
                              new List.generate(_alphabet.length,
                                  (index) => _getAlphabetItem(index)),
                            ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _getSpeechBubble() {
    return isPressed
        ? new SpeechBubble(
            nipLocation: NipLocation.RIGHT,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 30,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "${_text ?? "${_alphabet.first}"}",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        : SizedBox.shrink();
  }

  ValueGetter? callback(int value) {}

  _getAlphabetItem(int index) {
    return new Expanded(
      child: new Container(
        width: 40,
        height: 20,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: new Text(
          _alphabet[index],
          style: (index == posSelected)
              ? new TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)
              : new TextStyle(fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your `LayoutBuilder()` with `Expanded()` like this and it won't show an error.

```
return Container(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Text("Header"),
      Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount:50,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Text("List Item $index");
          },
        ),
      ),
      Text("Footer"),
    ],
  ),
);
```

You can try the code [here](https://dartpad.dev/e0960de55d709124a4efe01f98281988?null_safety=true)